# RxJS - Observable to a Model Object

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have started learning Observables in Angular and what I want should be fairly simple (I think) but I am obviously missing a vital step.

Here I subscribe to an observable which receives an array of type 'TheModel[]' back from an HTTP Get request (The service handles the HTTP calls)

[image]

The subscription should be assigning the object "TheModel[]" that comes back from the request to my local private object stated below.

[image]

But the console log value is stating "undefined".

[image]

The model is a simple ID, Name property class.

What is my misunderstanding?

Thanks

Comment: try to move console log inside of `subscribe`

Comment: The call is async. When console.log is called, TheModel is not ready yet.

Comment: Observable are asynchronous so the console.log(...) is called before you subscribe to the observable if the observable hasn't fully received the data from the http request yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The observables are asynchronous, so before you enter your `subscribe` method you are calling the `console.log` and at that point the value of `this.TheModel` is still undefined.

For this to work you should do something like the following

```js
this.dataservice.get('TheModel').pipe(...)
.subscribe(x => {
   this.TheModel = x;
   console.log(this.TheModel)
  })
```

You can imagine that the subscribe is the same thing as a async callback, you initialize the fetch, the code keeps running and once the data is retrieved you are invoking the subscribe method (just like a callback)